# I changed my PHP MySQL statement to a prepared statement, and floats changed decimal point from period to comma

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, floating-point

I have a MySQL table with floats in it. In PHPMyAdmin, they're listed as e.g. "55.123"

I used to pull them out using

```
$sql = "SELECT latitude,longitude FROM table WHERE id=" . $id;
$conn->query($sql);
```

When I print my floats, I get e.g. "55.123" - hardly surprising.
For obvious reasons I needed to change this query to a prepared statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT latitude,longitude FROM table WHERE id=?;";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Now, when I print my float, I get e.g. "55,123" - with a comma instead of with a period.

I suppose that my

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'da_DK.utf8');
```

might have something to do with this, but I really don't know what to do here. Because either I should stop changing my queries to prepared statements, or I should convert the floats to strings and replace the commas with periods. Either solution is less than ideal. Suggestions?

Comment: The traditional method returns all results as strings, using MySQL's formatting. When you use the newer method, floats in the database are returned as PHP floats, so PHP formats it according to the locale.

Comment: How do you print that number? I cannot reproduce it by using `echo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you are using an older version of PHP. Prior to PHP 8.0 locale setting affected the [conversion of floats to strings](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/locale_independent_float_to_string). This means that if you had a float and you used something like `echo` to output it out, the conversion to string would replace `.` with `,` for locales that use `,` for decimal separator. e.g.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE.UTF-8");
$number = 42.42;
echo $number; // outputs 42,42 in PHP 7
```

Once you upgrade to PHP 8 or newer, the output should be always the same irrespective of the locale.

---

As to why there's a difference between prepared and non-prepared queries in mysqli: mysqli prepared statements use a binary protocol (as opposed to textual) when talking to the database. This means that the data that arrives from MySQL is already an integer, float or string. It was decided that by default there will be no cast to a string. After all, what sense would that make? But to make the textual protocol compatible with binary one, an opt-in setting was added that would ask PHP to automatically cast numerical strings into PHP native integers and floats. You can enable that setting at any time by calling:

```
$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_INT_AND_FLOAT_NATIVE, true);
```

The binary protocol (prepared statements) ignores this setting.

I don't know why the setting is opt-in and not opt-out. PHP 8.1 changed this in PDO, but not in mysqli.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I am indeed running on PHP 7.4.32. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the prepared statement, you're also using the MySQL Native Driver (MYSQLND). When it fetches MySQL `FLOAT` columns, by default it returns them as PHP floats rather than strings. So PHP's locale is used when formatting them.

This is controlled by the option `MYSQLI_OPT_INT_AND_FLOAT_NATIVE`. You can unset this to get strings as before.

```
$conn->options(MYSQLI_OPT_INT_AND_FLOAT_NATIVE, false);
```

Note that this has to be called between creating the `mysqli` object and connecting to the server. So you can't use `new mysqli`, you have to call `mysqli_init()` and `$conn->real_connect()`:

```
$conn = mysqli_init();
$conn->options(MYSQLI_OPT_INT_AND_FLOAT_NATIVE, true);
$conn->real_connect('server', 'user', 'pass', 'database');
```

Comment: That option can be called after connecting to the server. It can be called at any time. Also, when not using prepared statements, you are also using mysqlnd. The only difference is which protocol is used.

Comment: @Dharman Interestingly, that MYSQLI_OPT_INT_AND_FLOAT_NATIVE [doesn't seem to affect prepared statements](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/d6336f9581c1a241c183afb477cacae9/), but only the regular query's outcome (yes I tested with real_connect too)

Comment: As whole, this answer is rather misleading. And it would have been much better if explained that locale issue mentioned in the comment above instead.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes, that setting is [unused with prepared statements.](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_wireprotocol.c#L1432) See that the parameter `as_int_or_float` is not used in that method, and it's only used in the next one.

Comment: @Dharman The documentation says "mysqli_options() should be called after mysqli_init() and before mysqli_real_connect()." I may have overstated by treating "should" as "must" -- perhaps it depends on the option, since some of them affect connecting and are meaningless after connecting.

Comment: I would delete this answer if the OP hadn't accepted it. But I upvoted your answer.